# Cannot open software center after upgrading to 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I just upgraded to 13.04 and when I tried to open software center it darkens and 'not responding'. I eventually had to force quit.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal **CTRL+ALT+T** and run **sudo apt-get -f install** to try fixing things for and reboot then recheck.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I did as what you asked and the problem still persists. However I could access the software center via terminal (even before running sudo apt-get -f install). Is there any other way to fix this?